# Xcode Simulator and Actual iPhones run Cordova App slow. Error Timed-out while waiting for reply for WebPage_TouchEventSync

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, debugging, timeout

I packaged and built my app in Cordova for iOS. When I try to run the app on an emulator in Xcode it is SUPER slow (5sec or so from interaction to reaction). This result is shown on NEWER iPhone models as well. I put the app on my old iPhone 6 and it runs fine. This application also runs flawlessly on android and windows.

In the debugger window the only thing that shows up during these slow interactions is the following:
[IPC] Connection::waitForSyncReply: Timed-out while waiting for reply for WebPage_TouchEventSync from process 21078, id = 13
When you click more while waiting for the app to load, it just adds more of this error with an incremental ID.

I am running the most recent version of Cordova (10.0.0) and built the app with the most recent Cordova IOS build version (6.2.0).

Please let me know if anyone has ran into similar issues.
Thanks!